# Unsecure content over https

Tags: javascript, ssl, https

I am getting the mixed content warning on a webapp I am working on when using the jsDatePick.

I have used fiddler and can confirm the problem is not caused by any image sources. 
When a date is selected the following line is run:

```
window.location.href = "\something\something\day?=date" + this.getSelectedDateFormatted();
```

Would this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Maybe its insecure due to depression :?

Comment: No, because the protocol is not specified it should inherit the protocol of the parent page. Look for anything calling "http://".

Comment: @Diodeus: I think that could be a nice answer.

Comment: (Not directly related, but) Note that the slashes should be `/forward/`, not `\backward\\` - if that call works, it's purely by accident.

Comment: Hmm, that is what I thought. I have checked, from looking at the code and fiddler there are no http connections what so ever. There are a few calls to remove child, which is the only other thing I can think of. See the below code block:JsDatePick.prototype.setTooltipText = function(aText){
 while (this.tooltip.firstChild){
  this.tooltip.removeChild(this.tooltip.firstChild);
 }

Comment: In IE9, simply press F12 and look at the console to find the insecure URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with a JsDatePick .js file.  I have the same issue (mixed content).  I'm unfortunately forced to use IE 8 for this project.  The parent page is https, and I've minimalized the page to the following (this minimal page still gets the mixed content pop-up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function()
{
new JsDatePick({
useMode:2,
target:"date_range1",
dateFormat:"%m/%d/%Y"
});

};
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1> Hey</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because the protocol is not specified it should inherit the protocol of the parent page. Look for anything calling "http://" instead of "https://" in your page source.